# how to install the latest version of redis?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to install the redis.2.6.0-rc7 cause i need the BITCOUNT command.I downloaded the package from [redis-2.6.0-rc7.tar.gz](http://redis.io/download)

when I finished the make && make install,I checked the version of redis-cli,it shows

```
redis-cli 2.5.13
```

why isn't be 2.6.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because 2.6 has still to be officially released. With Redis, odd version numbers are development versions, even numbers are release versions. 2.6RC7 is still a development version, and therefore labeled as 2.5.something.

Comment: Thanks.However,I don't understand what you said.So the 2.5.something is actually the 2.6.0 version?But it doesn't support the 2.6 commands,I'd better try the github to obtain the latest code.

Comment: @cheneydeng: Yes, version 2.5.13 is also the *release candidate* for 2.6.0, indeed the seventh. If it passes the test, it will become 2.6.0. If not, there will be an eighth release candidate.